# Where did my bookmarks go?

Tags: support, bookmarks

Okay, so now when I hit the 'bookmark' icon, the question is now 'saved', and now there's a 'Saves' tab in my profile. Fine, sure, whatever.

But where did my old bookmarks go? And if there is somewhere they went that I can still find them, why doesn't the new Saves tab inform me of that?

(I'm using the Android version of the web site.)

Comment: Relevant on Meta SE: [All (or some) of my bookmarks or saved posts seem to have disappeared! What happened?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382588)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I noticed basically the same problem about $5$ hours ago, and even posted [New "Saves" feature is now only partially implemented, with it currently apparently being unusable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382564/562482) about this on the network Meta site. However, I quite quickly deleted my question because a comment to it pointed me to [Bookmarks have evolved into Saves](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382019/562482), which now initially states

> **Update Oct 4:** Saves is now officially live on Stack Overflow and across Stack Exchange sites! The migration process will take some time to process as there are millions of bookmarked questions to migrate over. If you’re not seeing any questions you previously bookmarked, that means they haven’t been processed yet.

Comment: Thanks. I wondered if the was an announcement somewhere on one of the network/Meta sites, but I don't know my way around them. I think I'll keep my question up here, in case there are others who wonder the same thing, and are similarly unable to navigate the network/meta sites.

Comment: (And having just checked that post on meta.stackexchange, yeesh, I think I'm going to keep avoiding it. I thought we were contentious here on math.meta!)

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I will just mention that the link to the announcement is shown in the [meta-tag:community-bulletin] - the place on the RHS when you're browsing meta. I have posted screenshot in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/64952/2022/10/5 https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64952/conversation/bookmarks-are-now-saves (just in case it's not clear where the CB is). But I understand that such announcement are easy to overlook - in the past, I have missed some posts which were shown there and contained useful information.

Comment: Thanks, @MartinSleziak. It's true that I tend not to notice that. Also, it is all the way at the bottom on mobile, and it currently isn't showing anything for me about the bookmarks to saves migration, so odds are I'm going to continue to not notice it. :-)

Comment: I encountered the same "problem" yesterday. Suddenly all my bookmarks were gone without me changing anything. Yesterday, however, there was not yet the Saves tab in the profile menu. 

I have to admit that I was a bit annoyed because these bookmarks have been accumulated partly over years. Then this morning I discovered that there was the Saves tab and everything was fine.

I had also written to support (yesterday) via mail about this, but unfortunately they only said that my bookmarks could not be restored. A reference to the (new) Saves tab, however, was not there...